# Dynamic Radio Box Generation on Div Tag

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic-controls

I have a requirement where I need to generate dynamic controls in a specific html order of 
I tried many options like adding controls to div tag via `div.controls.add(radioButton)` and added `html` like `div.InnerHtml()` etc, but never got the controls rendered on the page I wanted.

Only this structure has helped me but this method has some disadvantages and I would want to avoid this. Please, review my code below and suggest if I can come up with something else that is more convenient.

```
foreach (var pair in dictionary) {
    if (pair.Value.Count > 0) {
        divDay = divDay + "<tr>";
        divDay = divDay + "<td>";
        divDay = divDay + pair.Key.DayOfWeek.ToString() + " " + pair.Key.Date.ToString("MMMM");
        divDay = divDay + "</td>";

        divDay = divDay + "<td>";
        appointment_days.InnerHtml = divDay;
        foreach (Appointment appointment in pair.Value) {
            string radioButtonHtml = string.Format("<input type=\"radio\" id=\"{0}\" runat=\"server\">{1}</input>",
                appointment.AppointmentCode.ToString() + "_" + appointment.AppointmentStart.Value.ToShortDateString() + "_" + appointment.AppointmentEnd.Value.ToShortDateString(),
                appointment.AppointmentStart.Value.TimeOfDay.ToString() + "-" + appointment.AppointmentEnd.Value.TimeOfDay.ToString()
            );

            divDay = divDay + radioButtonHtml;
        }
        divDay = divDay + "</td>";
        divDay = divDay + "</tr>";
    }
}
divDay = divDay + "</table>";
appointment_days.InnerHtml = divDay;
```

Comment: StringBuilder (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Can you add RadioButton Controls to Controls collection of parent control?

Comment: Dovydas Soda, yes I used stringbuilder and string, it did not help.

Comment: Emanuel, what you are saying I tried, the HTML was not rendering with thee logic you are mentioning. I had a panel in an ascx and inside a panel I had a div that was running on a server, the control render would be either the checkbox but not in table nor the html I was wanting it